# Wordpress - Shared link 404 on Facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I've read various posts and can't seem to solve this one.

I have an issue that with sharing links form a wordpress site facebook returning a 404.

I have the standard .htaccess file.
I'm not using gzip.
No caching plugins.

I am using Yoast. Which is adding the correct meta data.

If I pop this url (below) in the facebook debugger I get a 404

[Edit: URL Dead now]

If I pop the shortlink (below) for that post in the facebook debugger I get `Object at URL 'http://example.com/?p=7229' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.`

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

**EDIT**

The site is running on a dedicated server. Is there something I can check there? I'm still totally puzzled by this and I've been reading and trying things for hours!

**RESOVLED**
I am using a dedicated 1and1 server, within the settings in Plesk the IPv6 address was set to `none`. As soon as I added a IPv6 address it all worked!

Comment: try to update your permalink

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried that and it didn't help.

Comment: Have a look through your WP plugins – you are probably using one that tries to block requests by any kind of “bots”.

Comment: Hi, I don't have any with that ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a dedicated 1and1 server, within the settings in Plesk the IPv6 address was set to none. As soon as I added a IPv6 address it all worked!