# Wordpress - Page renders fine, Web Sniffer returning HTTP Response Header 404

Tags: wordpress, header, http-status-code-404

I hope someone can help, I've been going round and round in circles. I've tried calling my host 1and1 they basically told me it's nothing to do with them.

All my Wordpress pages render fine to the eye of the user.

However if I use http://web-sniffer.net and put any page other than the homepage it returns a 404 status.

The .htaccess file is the standard Wordpress one. I don't have any caching plugins installed.

Could anyone tell me how I fix this? Or what on earth is going on? I've been at this for hours reading tonnes of posts to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a dedicated 1and1 server, within the settings in Plesk the IPv6 address was set to none. As soon as I added a IPv6 address it all worked!

Note I had another issue that Facebook wasn't able to scrape my URLs, this also fixed that. [Wordpress - Shared link 404 on Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678779/wordpress-shared-link-404-on-facebook)